# Can't texture small wall without it looking weird or artifacts on the edges

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv, shaders

I created a small wall, next to a road and put some pbr wall texture on it. I am trying forever to get rid of these artifacts and thought it is because of uv mapping. First I did cube projection because it is basically just a long cube, but it looked weird. Now I manually uv mapped it again and it still looks weird. I don't know if it is because I did something wrong or if there is just a better way of doing what I am trying to do. Would appreciate any help.

Thats the wall. The front face is not visible in the render

[image: Thats the wall. The front face is not visible in the render]

Thats my mesh. I beveled first and then subdivided, thats why I ended up with more edges on the corner edge. I then used Subdivision surface with a pbr and adaptive sampling and set the material settings of displacement to discplacement and bump.

[image]

This is how it looks in rendered view.

[image]
[image]